# Obtaining predictions on test datasets for k-fold cross validation in caret

Tags: r, prediction, r-caret, cross-validation

I'm a little confused how caret scores the test folds in k-fold cross validation.

I'd like to generate a data frame or matrix containing the scored records of the ten test datasets in 10-fold cross validation.

For example, using the iris dataset to train a decision tree model:

```
install.packages("caret", dependencies=TRUE) 

library(caret)

data(iris)

train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10, savePredictions = TRUE), 

model <- train(Species ~ ., data=iris, trControl=train_control, method="rpart")

model$pred
```

The `model$pred` command lists predictions for ten folds in 450 records.

This doesn't seem right - shouldn't `model$pred` produce predictions for the **150 records** in the ten test folds (1/10 * 150 = 15 records per test fold)? How are 450 records generated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `train` iterates over three values for the complexity parameter `cp` of `rpart` (see `?rpart.control`):

```
library(caret)
data(iris)
train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10, savePredictions = TRUE) 

model <- train(Species ~ ., 
               data=iris, 
               trControl=train_control, 
               method="rpart")
nrow(model$pred)
# [1] 450
length(unique(model$pred$cp))
# [1] 3
```

You can change that for example by explicitly specifying `cp=0.05`:

```
model <- train(Species ~ ., 
               data=iris, 
               trControl=train_control, 
               method="rpart", 
               tuneGrid = data.frame(cp = 0.05))
nrow(model$pred)
# [1] 150
length(unique(model$pred$cp))
# [1] 1
```

or by using `tuneLength=1` instead of the default `3`:

```
model <- train(Species ~ ., 
               data=iris, 
               trControl=train_control, 
               method="rpart", 
               tuneLength = 1)
nrow(model$pred)
# [1] 150
length(unique(model$pred$cp))
# [1] 1
```

Comment: Thanks lukeA! I need to take care to specify the tuning parameters for each procedure.

Comment: Alternative, you can specify the argument  `savePredictions="final"`